# Why do the references for my Form1 object and my instantiated class Guess not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm new to Windows Forms and I'm having trouble making this program work as the Form1 reference 'form' spits out this error: "The name 'form' does not exists in the current context" for every use of it and the reference variable 'guess' that instantiates the Guess class is giving me this error: "The type or namespace name 'guess' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" for every use. I'm sure I'm making a simple mistake but I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Guess class

```
using System;
namespace GuessingGame
{  
public class Guess
{
    private int guess;
    private int guessCount;
    private Random r = new Random();
    private int number;

    public int Guess { get; set; }
    public int GuessCount { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }

    public Guess()
    {
        this.guessCount = 0;
        number = r.Next(0, 101);
    }

    public Guess(int num)
    {
        this.guess = num;
        this.guessCount++;
        number = r.Next(0, 101);
    }

    public void addNumber(int num)
    {
        this.guess = num;
        this.guessCount++;
    }

    public bool isHigher()
    {
        if (guess > number)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool isEqual()
    {
        if (guess == number)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        number = r.Next(0, 101);
        guess = 0;
        guessCount = 0;
    }

}
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
// Form1.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuessingGame
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        guess.reset();
        txtBxEnterNumber.Text = "";
        txtBxGuessCount = guess.GuessCount;
        form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnGuess_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        string inValue;
        int number;
        while (int.TryParse(txtBxEnterNumber.Text, out number) == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter an integer only");
            txtBxEnterNumber.Text = "";
            txtBxEnterNumber.Focus();
        }

        Guess guess = new Guess(number);
        txtBxGuessCount.Text = guess.GuessCount;
        if (guess.isEqual())
        {
            form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            btnReset.Focus();
        }
        else if (guess.isHigher())
        {
            form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
            txtBxEnterNumber.Text = "";
            txtBxEnterNumber.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            form.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            txtBxEnterNumber.Text = "";
            txtBxEnterNumber.Focus();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And finally Program.cs, which for some reason was not automatically created when I made the Windows Forms project so I created it myself. Perhaps that is contributing to the problem.

```
using System;
namespace GuessingGame
{
static class Program
{
    static void main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        Application.Run(form);

        Guess guess = new Guess();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what it is you're trying to accomplish. Paring the example down to a good [mcve] and being very _specific_ about what exactly it is you want the code to do would help. That said, in your `Form1` class, you don't need the `form` variable (from your `main()` method, I presume you are trying to use). Just use `this`. As for `guess`, there's no `guess` field in the `Form1` class you show, so probably you just need to add that. Please improve the question.

Comment: It should be `Main` not `main`, and go to your Project Properties and change it from a Windows Form Application (which looks for a startup form) to a Class Library, then you can choose the Startup object as your Main method. (I believe, I haven't done this recently.)

Comment: Thanks, that gave me my Program.cs file finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you created them in the context of the main() method. The classes themselves are a totally different context. Within a Form1 method, "this" refers to the Form1 instance you're in. If you want Form1 to be able to use the "guess" instance, you must pass it in and store it somehow. Try something like this:

In main:

```
Guess guess = new Guess();
Form1 form = new Form1(guess);
```

In the Form1 class:

```
private Guess guess;

public Form1(Guess guess)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.guess = guess;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.guess.reset();
    this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
}
```

Comment: I'll note, also, that this question doesn't just show that you're new to Windows Forms, it shows that you are new to object-oriented programming of any form.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am pretty new to OOP. Unfortunately I'm taking classes on-line and my teacher isn't returning my emails asking for help as usualy so this website is my only hope.

Comment: I've worked on the program and fixed what you showed me as well as done what the other commenter mentioned of setting the start-up object in project properties. I'm still getting the same errors though. Could it be that I need to have a using statement for the Guess class or something? (I did fix the Form1 reference variable by changing what you suggested and changing all of my reference to this. like you said. Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this question if you'd mention the line the error occurs at.

Comment: Oh, ok. Twice in line 19 of Program.cs where I define the guess object. And also lines 15 and 17 of Form1.cs which is where I define the private Guess reference and pass the guess into the Form1 constructor.

Comment: Well i pasted the guess class after the main method, and I got some new errors that I think I can handle and the old ones went away. I think it just wasn't registering it in a separate file for some reason.